# Merging two pandas dataframes and leaving only columns and rows with difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for an effective way to compare two dataframes, in a way when only rows and columns with different values will remain. Assuming the dataframes are:

df1:

| pet_name | exam_day | result_1 | result_2 | pre_result_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Patrick | 2023-01-01 | 1 | 10 | 123 |
| Patrick | 2023-01-02 | **2** | 20 | 123 |
| Patrick | 2023-01-03 | 3 | 30 | 123 |
| Patrick | 2023-01-04 | 4 | 40 | 123 |

df2:

| pet_name | exam_day | result_1 | result_2 | pre_result_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Patrick | 2023-01-01 | 1 | 10 | 123 |
| Patrick | 2023-01-02 | **99** | 20 | 123 |
| Patrick | 2023-01-03 | 3 | 30 | 123 |
| Patrick | 2023-01-04 | 4 | 40 | 123 |

There is one difference between them in 2nd row, column: result_1
So far I came up with:

```
pets_diff = df1.merge(
            df2,
            indicator=True,
            how="outer",
        )
pets_diff = pets_diff[lambda x: x["_merge"] != "both"]
```

This will remove all matching rows, leaving only those with differences, like this:

| pet_name | exam_day | result_1 | result_2 | pre_result_1 | _merge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Patrick** | **2023-01-02** | **2** | 20 | 123 | left_only |
| **Patrick** | **2023-01-02** | **99** | 20 | 123 | right_only |

I would like to end up with the following dataframe:

| pet_name | exam_day | result_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Patrick** | **2023-01-02** | **2** |
| **Patrick** | **2023-01-02** | **99** |

Notice that all rows and columns with same values are gone.
I would like leave `dimension` columns: **pet_name** and **exam_day** and remove all other columns that have matching values. Please note there are 300+ columns that might have different values and names (result_1, result_2, pre_result_1, post_exam_33, etc).

Comment: Are same index and columns names in both DataFrames? What is output if change one `40` to `100` in df1?

Comment: What about if one row has a difference in `result_1` and another in `post_exam_33`? Are both columns in the result dataframe?

Comment: @jezrael the only common columns in both dataframes are pet_name and exam_day. The rest can be different, but in that case it should be also returned in final dataframe

Comment: @Nick Yes, both should end up in final dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html):

```
out = (df1.set_index(['pet_name','exam_day'])
          .compare(df2.set_index(['pet_name','exam_day']), align_axis=0)
          .droplevel(-1)
          .reset_index())

print (out)
#40 in df2 is changed to 100
  pet_name    exam_day  result_1  result_2
0  Patrick  2023-01-02       2.0       NaN
1  Patrick  2023-01-02      99.0       NaN
2  Patrick  2023-01-04       NaN      40.0
3  Patrick  2023-01-04       NaN     100.0
```

**Detail**:

```
print(df1.set_index(['pet_name','exam_day'])
          .compare(df2.set_index(['pet_name','exam_day']), align_axis=0))
                           result_1  result_2
pet_name exam_day                            
Patrick  2023-01-02 self        2.0       NaN
                    other      99.0       NaN
         2023-01-04 self        NaN      40.0
                    other       NaN     100.0
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about `compare` function.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Rather than using `.stack`, you can simply specify `align_axis=0` to `compare`

Comment: @Nick - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `numpy` and on [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
idxx, idxy = np.where(df1.values != df2.values)
idxy = np.unique(idxy)
pd.concat([df1.iloc[np.tile(idxx, 2),:2], 
           pd.concat([df1.iloc[(idxx, idxy)], df2.iloc[(idxx, idxy)]])], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  pet_name    exam_day  result_1
1  Patrick  2023-01-02         2
1  Patrick  2023-01-02        99
```