# Group by 2 of 3 columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, charts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntTJv.png)I am wanting to take a list of vehicle classes 1-12, vehicle makes and models and print a 12 row table/chart, respective makes and models in each class row. something like:

```
Class | Make  | Model
________________________
      | Acura |SLX
1     | Acura |TLX
      | Ford  |Fusion
_________________________
      | Acura |CSX
2     | Ford  |F150
      | Ford  |Expedition
```

Tried this:
The code below groups the repeats the same make in a row, same for the models, plus it doesnt show the class column when i save it to a new csv.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tabulate import tabulate

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
#df_size = df.shape
df2 = df.drop(['VIN', 'Class Guide Line Item #', 'Asset Type', 'Year', 'Trim','Trim Option 1', 'Trim Option 2','Trim Option 3','Trim Option 4'], axis='columns')
df2.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
#print(tabulate(df2, headers="keys", showindex="never", tablefmt="fancy_grid"))
df2.head()
df3.groupby(['Class']).agg(list)
df3.groupby(['Class']).agg(pd.Series.tolist)

#df3 = df2.groupby(['Class']).agg(lambda x: list(x))
#print(tabulate(df3, headers="keys", showindex="never", tablefmt="grid"))
df3.head()
#df3.to_csv('newdata.csv', index=False)
```

Desired Output would be :

### Class| Make | Model

```
 | Acura| SLX, TLX
```

### 1    | Ford | Fusion

```
 | Acura| CSX
```

### 2    | Ford | F150, Expedition

and so on.

Comment: What output is the input you provided as an example converted to?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (images of data are not acceptable), and be explicit about the type of output that you expect (a DataFrame? a CSV?) by providing a reproducible object for that as well.

Comment: @PandaKim - not sure what you mean. I want to essentially export this into excel to keep the format. My output groups it by classes but then lists out the makes and models. I would like to have it list out the Makes once per class, then list out each corresponding models to the same row as the class and make combo.

Comment: @joedady16 read mozway linked post. and provide MRE and desired output as text.

I think what you provided is a sample of the input, so I asked you to provide only the desired output. But if not, please provide both. If you are new to SO, it would be a good idea to read the announcements and ask questions

Comment: I provided a sample of the output in a snip. it's linked to the my initial description

Comment: @joedady16 As mozway commented, [images are not allowed.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) and need exact desired output. **Please provide example of input([mre]) as text and exact desired output as text.** Typically, you can get a response within 10 minutes if you ask a question in accordance with the guidelines of Stack Overflow. The reason you are not getting a proper response is that your question needs to be modified in many ways. That's why we are making suggestions in the comments

Comment: Refer to this [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77605724/merging-two-pandas-dataframes-and-leaving-only-columns-and-rows-with-difference). **The input is provided as text** in a minimal example for reproducibility. The desired output is also provided as a table in clear text.

Comment: @PandaKim ok i added the output

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solution:

```
def format_class_column22(group):
    group['Class'] = [''] * len(group)
    group.iloc[0, group.columns.get_loc('Class')] = group.name
    return group

# applying the formatting function to each group
df = df.groupby('Class').apply(format_class_column22)
# resetting the index to remove the multi-level index created by groupby
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", showindex="never", tablefmt="fancy_grid"))
# grouping by 'Make' and concatenating the 'Model' values
grouped_make_model = df.groupby('Make')['Model'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()
print(tabulate(grouped_make_model, headers="keys", showindex="never", tablefmt="fancy_grid"))
```

[image]

Comment: This isnt working for me. I get this error:     group.columns.get_loc('Class')] = group.name
      4     return group
----> 6 df3.groupby(['Class']).apply(format_class_column)
      7 df3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
      
DataFrame.groupby(self, by, axis, level, as_index, sort, group_keys, observed, dropna)
   8249     raise TypeError("You have to supply one of 'by' and 'level'")
   8250 axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
-> 8252 return DataFrameGroupBy(

Comment: oops, scratch that. I commented by df3 assignment. I got the table now. How can I take it a step further, and group the makes, then list out the Models in the same row as its make?